# TypeError: argument 0 is not a Variable

Tags: variables, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I am trying to learn CNN with my own data. The shape of the data is `(1224, 15, 23)`. 1224 is the number of data, and each data is `(15, 23)`. CNN is built with PyTorch.

I think there is no logical error because conv2D needs 4-D tensor, and I feed `(batch, channel, x, y)`.

when I build an instance of the Net class I got this error.

```
TypeError: argument 0 is not a Variable
```

I have been using PyTroch for half of a year but this error is the first time and I am still confused.

Here is my code.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super(Net,self).__init__()

        self.conv = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1),  # 64 x 9 x 17
                                 nn.ReLU()
                                )

        conv_out_size = self._get_conv_out(input_shape)
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(64 * 9 * 17, 128),
                               nn.ReLU(),
                               nn.Linear(128, n)
                               )

    def _get_conv_out(self, shape):
        o = self.conv(torch.zeros(1, *shape))
        return int(np.prod(o.size()))

    def forward(self, x):
        conv_out = self.conv(x).view(x.size()[0], -1)
        return sefl.fc(conv_out)
```

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    num_epochs = 1
    num_classes = 2
    input_shape = train_img[0].shape  # 1, 15, 23

    net = Net(num_classes)
    iteration = 51
    BATCH_SIZE = 24 
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

    loss_list= []
    batch_index = 0

    # train
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i in range(iteration):
            input_img = torch.FloatTensor(train_img[batch_index: batch_index + BATCH_SIZE])
            print(input_img.size())  # 24, 1, 15, 23

            outputs = net(input_img)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss_list.append(loss.item())

            # Backprop
            opimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
```

And the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-179-0f6bc7588c29> in <module>
      4     input_shape = train_img[0].shape  # 1, 15, 23
      5 
----> 6     net = Net(num_classes)
      7     iteration = 51
      8     BATCH_SIZE = 24

<ipython-input-178-8a68d4a0dc4a> in __init__(self, n)
     11                                 )
     12 
---> 13         conv_out_size = self._get_conv_out(input_shape)
     14         self.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(64 * 9 * 17, 128),
     15                                nn.ReLU(),

<ipython-input-178-8a68d4a0dc4a> in _get_conv_out(self, shape)
     18 
     19     def _get_conv_out(self, shape):
---> 20         o = self.conv(torch.zeros(1, *shape))
     21         return int(np.prod(o.size()))
     22 

C:\DTools\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    355             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    356         else:
--> 357             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    358         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    359             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

C:\DTools\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py in forward(self, input)
     65     def forward(self, input):
     66         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 67             input = module(input)
     68         return input
     69 

C:\DTools\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    355             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    356         else:
--> 357             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    358         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    359             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

C:\DTools\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py in forward(self, input)
    280     def forward(self, input):
    281         return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 282                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    283 
    284 

C:\DTools\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in conv2d(input, weight, bias, stride, padding, dilation, groups)
     88                 _pair(0), groups, torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark,
     89                 torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic, torch.backends.cudnn.enabled)
---> 90     return f(input, weight, bias)
     91 
     92 

TypeError: argument 0 is not a Variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works for `PyTorch >= 0.4.1`. I guess your PyTorch version is < 0.4 and so you need to pass a Variable in the following line.

```
o = conv(torch.autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, *x.shape)))
```

In `PyTorch >= 0.4.1`, the concept of Variable no longer exists. So, `torch.FloatTensor` can be directly passed to NN layers.

Comment: Thanks u. I was using pytorhc version 0.3.0  // and i got it upgraded so it worked fine